# Determining if all attributes on a javascript object are null or an empty string

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, attributes

What is the most elegant way to determine if all attributes in a javascript object are either null or the empty string?  It should work for an arbitrary number of attributes.

```
{'a':null, 'b':''} //should return true for this object
{'a':1, 'b':''} //should return false for this object
{'a':0, 'b':1} //should return false
{'a':'', 'b':''} //should return true
```

Comment: No matter what, you'll have to loop through all the elements in the object and check each one.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Create a function to loop and check:

```
function checkProperties(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] !== null && obj[key] != "")
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var obj = {
    x: null,
    y: "",
    z: 1
}

checkProperties(obj) //returns false
```

Comment: @ J-Bob: This or adeneo's answer should get you started. If you also want to allow `undefined`, change the `=== null` to `== null`. And you may or may not want to add a `hasOwnProperty` check, depending on whether you care about properties from prototypes. (adeneo's answer only checks "own" properties, tymeJV's does both "own" and prototype). Or perhaps a check ignoring properties referring to functions (again, if desired).

Answer (score 198):

Check all values with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). It returns an array with the values, which you can check with [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const isEmpty = Object.values(object).every(x => x === null || x === '');
```

```js
const isEmpty = !Object.values(object).some(x => x !== null && x !== '');
```

Comment: or shorter:  Object.values(object).every(x => !!x);

Comment: @JonathanMeguira This is not what the OP is asking for. Checking for falsy includes way more then an empty string or null.

Comment: @abd995 That’s not correct. `some` and `every` are _equally_ efficient and equally fast. They both implement short-circuit evaluation: as soon as `some` hits a value for which the condition doesn’t hold, the iteration stops, yes, but the same thing applies to `every`.

Comment: `array.some(Boolean)` & `array.every(Boolean)` excels here, too. (be mindful of `0`'s though).

Answer (score 30):

Here's my version, specifically checking for null and empty strings (would be easier to just check for falsy)

```
function isEmptyObject(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).every(function(x) {
        return o[x]===''||o[x]===null;  // or just "return o[x];" for falsy values
    });
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
let obj = { x: null, y: "hello", z: 1 };
let obj1 = { x: null, y: "", z: 0 };

!Object.values(obj).some(v => v);
// false

!Object.values(obj1).some(v => v);
// true
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 10):

Quick and simple solution:

```
Object.values(object).every(value => !!value);
```

Comment: `{'a':'', 'b':''}` will return false. OP want return true

Comment: This does not work when the array is like `{'a':'', 'b': null, e: undefined}`. I have to use
`["", undefined, null].every(value => !value); `

Answer (score 9):

Using `Array.some()` and check if the values are not `null` and not `empty` is **more efficient** than using `Array.every` and check it the other way around.

```
const isEmpty = !Object.values(object).some(x => (x !== null && x !== ''));
```

This answer should just make the excellent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427583/238134) of user [abd995](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10623752/abd995) more visible.

Comment: That comment is wrong, though. Both methods are equally efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Array.reduce prototype on your object's keys.

Assuming that the object is structured as follows:

```
var obj = {
    x: null,
    y: "",
    z: 1
}
```

you can use the following instruction to discover if all of it's properties are unset or set to empty string using just one line:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, k) => res && !(!!obj[k] || obj[k] === false || !isNaN(parseInt(obj[k]))), true) // returns false
```

If you want to discover if all of it's properties are set instead you have  to remove the negation before the conditions and set the initial result value to true only if the object has keys:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, k) => res && (!!obj[k] || obj[k] === false || !isNaN(parseInt(obj[k]))), Object.keys(obj).length > 0) // returns false as well
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on adeneo's answer, I created a single line condition. Hope it will be helpful to someone.

```
var test = {
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "name": "Test",
  "mobile": "9876543210",
  "address": {
      "street": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "country": "",
      "postalcode": "r"
  },
  "website": "www.test.com"
};

if (Object.keys(test.address).every(function(x) { return test.address[x]===''||test.address[x]===null;}) === false) {
   console.log('has something');
} else {
   console.log('nothing');
}
```

You can test it https://jsfiddle.net/4uyue8tk/2/

Answer (score 5):

Just complementing the past answers: they'll work if your object doesn't contain arrays or objects. If it does, you'll need to do a 'deep check'.

So I came up with this solution. It'll evaluate the object as empty if **all** its values (and values inside values) are `undefined`, `{}` or `[]`.

```
function deepCheckEmptyObject(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).every( value => {
        if (value === undefined) return true;
        else if ((value instanceof Array || value instanceof Object) && _.isEmpty(value) ) return true;
        else if (value instanceof Array && !_.isEmpty(value)) return deepCheckEmptyArray(value);
        else if (value instanceof Object && !_.isEmpty(value)) return deepCheckEmptyObject(value);
        else return false;
    });
}

function deepCheckEmptyArray(array) {
    return array.every( value => {
        if (value === undefined) return true;
        else if ((value instanceof Array || value instanceof Object) && _.isEmpty(value)) return true;
        else if (value instanceof Array && !_.isEmpty(value)) return deepCheckEmptyArray(value);
        else if (value instanceof Object && !_.isEmpty(value)) return deepCheckEmptyObject(value);
        else return false;
    });
}
```

Note it uses Lodash's `.isEmpty()` to do the heavy work after we 'isolated' a value. Here, Lodash is imported as '_'.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Also if you are searching for only values are empty within the object,

```js
Object.values({ key: 0, key2: null, key3: undefined, key4: '' }).some(e => Boolean(e))
// false

Object.values({ key: 0, key2: null, key3: undefined, key4: "hello" }).some(e => Boolean(e))
// true

Object.values({ key: 1, key2: "hello" }).some(e => Boolean(e))
// true
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on tymeJv's answer =)

```
function checkProperties(obj) {
var state = true;
  for (var key in obj) {
    if ( !( obj[key] === null || obj[key] === "" ) ) {
        state = false;
        break;
    }
  }
  return state;
}

var obj = {
  x: null,
  y: "",
  z: 1
}

checkProperties(obj) //returns false
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all the keys from the object which is empty, undefined and null

```
Object.keys(obj).filter((k)=> {
  if (obj[k] === "" || obj[k]===undefined || obj[k]===null) {
    return k;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of other answers I would use lodash to check `isEmpty` on the object, as well as its properties.

```
const isEmpty = (object) => return _.isEmpty(object) || !Object.values(object).some(x => !_.isEmpty(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This skip the function attribute

```js
function checkIsNull(obj){
  let isNull=true;
  for(let key in obj){
   if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] !== 'function') {
    isNull = false;
   }
  }
  return isNull;
 }

var objectWithFunctionEmpty={
  "name":undefined,
  "surname":null,
  "fun": function (){ alert('ciao'); }
}

var objectWithFunctionFull={
  "name":undefined,
  "surname":"bla bla",
  "fun": function (){ alert('ciao'); }
}

checkIsNull(objectWithFunctionEmpty); //true
checkIsNull(objectWithFunctionFull); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with me perfectly:

```
checkProperties(obj) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let key in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== "");
  }
  return arr.includes(false);
}
```

This will return true or false if there is at-least one value is empty or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method to get all the object's values (as an array of object's values) and then check if this array of values contains **null** or **""** values, with the help of [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes) method prvided by [lodash](https://lodash.com) library.

```js
const checkObjectProperties = obj => {
  const objValues = Object.keys(obj);

  if (_.includes(objValues, "") || _.includes(objValues, null)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true
  }
  
  const incorrectObjProps = { one: null, two: "", three: 78 }
  const correctObjProps = { one: "some string" }
  
  checkObjectProperties(incorrectObjProps) // return false
  checkObjectProperties(correctObjProps) // return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my two sense:

```js
Object.values(object).every(value => Boolean(value));
```

Comment: this wont allow whitespaces also => 


`var stateIsValid = Object.values(this.state).every((value) => Boolean(String(value).trim()))`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
function checkValues(obj) {
  var objValues = Object.values(obj);
  if (objValues.length < 1) return false;
  return objValues.every((value) => {
    if (value === null) return true;
    if (typeof(value) == 'string')
      if(!(value || false))
        return true;
    return false;
  });
}
// OR
Object.values( obj ).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
);
```

Testing:

```js
checkValues({ a: null, b: '' });
// OR
Object.values({ a: null, b: '' }).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
);
// Output: true

checkValues({ a: '', b: '' });
// OR
Object.values({ a: '', b: '' }).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
);
// Output: true

checkValues({ a: 0, b: '' });
// OR
Object.values({ a: 0, b: '' }).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
)
// Output: false

checkValues({ a: 0, b: 1 });
// OR
Object.values({ a: 0, b: 1 }).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
)
// Output: false

checkValues({ a: 1, b: '' });
// OR
Object.values({ a: 1, b: '' }).every(
  value => value === null || (typeof(value) == 'string' && !(value || false))
)
// Output: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Object.values()` method to get all of the object's values (as an array of object's values) and then check if this array of values contains null or "", with the help of methods provided by the lodash library.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have the following object

```
obj = {'a':'', 'b': null, e: undefined}
```

The function to check object has empty value for all keys

```
const isEmptyObj = (obj) => {
    return Object.values(obj).every(val => !val); 
}
```

Now the function call `isEmptyObj(obj)` will return `true`.

Let us consider another object

```
obj1 = {'a':'', 'b': null, e: undefined, f: 21}
```

The function call `isEmptyObj(obj1)` will return `false`.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
!Object.values(yourObject).join('')
```

Comment: pro tip: you can add code fences to format the code