# Ajax success: Data length Undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why am I getting undefined in data.length in the ajax.sucess?

Here is the code,some parts have removed for sake of brevity:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    url: urlGetProviderQualificationTimeData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#providerqualification-main").show();
            $("#tblProviders").show();
            SetHeaderFields(data);
        } else {
            $("#NoRecordFound").show();
            $("#providerqualification-main").hide();
        }
    },
    complete: function (e) {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: check like if(data.hasOwnProperty('Address')) {// code here }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get object length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length)

Comment: Console the response data.

If it is an array or string `length` of data will be defined.

If the response is an object, use `Object.keys(data).length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `data` object doesn't have a `length` property (and Object's don't have one as Arrays do), so it's `undefined`.

Given the context of your code you simply want to check if the returned object has some data within it. If so, you can use this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (!data || !Object.keys(data).length) {
        $("#NoRecordFound").show();
        $("#providerqualification-main").hide();
    } else {
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#providerqualification-main").show();
        $("#tblProviders").show();
        SetHeaderFields(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this mean that if any of the property would be null, it will be true?

Comment: No, it checks if the object exists and that it has at least one property. The value of that property can be null and it would still pass as valid

Comment: OK. So my data has Object and in it I have properties. Still it doesn't pass the if condition and goes into the else.

Comment: That's correct behaviour, as I said, if the object has properties (no matter what their value is) it will hit the `else` statement above

Comment: So there is no way I can check if those properties have null or not?

Comment: Yes there is, you need to loop through the object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709636/determning-if-all-attributes-on-a-javascript-object-are-null-or-the-empty-string