# How to check if key value pair in a array of objects in empty using react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have the data like below,

```
data = [
  { 
    attributes: [{key: '', value: ''}, {key: 'name1', value: ''}],
    info: '',
    meshes: [],
  }
  {
   attributes: [{key: '', value: ''}, {key: '', value: ''}],
   info: '',
   meshes: [],
  }
   .....so on.... 
  ]
```

So from above data i want to check if each attributes has key and value empty or undefined. how can i check that. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What result do you expect? Do you want to filter `data`? Do you want a boolean result if any object in the array does not match your conditions?

Comment: Iterate over `data` and check the object property `attributes`.

Comment: Both the empty string and `undefined` are falsy

Comment: `data.every(x => x.every(a => a.key === '' && a.value === ''))`

Comment: this seems to be the right one thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709636/determining-if-all-attributes-on-a-javascript-object-are-null-or-an-empty-string).

Try the following codes below:

```
function isEmptyObject(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).every(function(x) {
        return o[x]===''||o[x]===null;  // or just "return o[x];" for falsy values
    });
}
```

or

```
const isEmpty = Object.values(object).every(x => (x === null || x === ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Firstly, iterate over data`, then, `check length of attribute array`

```
data.forEach(attr => {
  if(attr.length > 0){
    // attr contains key and value
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let x in data) {
  for (let y in data[x].attributes) {
    if ((key === '') || (value === '')) {
      return ('data:' + x + 'attribute:' + y + 'missing key or value');
    }
  }
}
```

Untested.
Loops through all data and attributes to test for empty key/value. You can add an extra else if to check for value and key separately.