# How to check in a fast way if the parameters of a class are null or ''?

Tags: ionic4

Hi everyone i'm trying to check for example before to create a document on a collection in Firebase, if the object.name, object.title, object.velocity... are just a white space ('') or if they are **null** in typescript (Ionic 4), but i think there is another way more fast, what is the best recomendation to deal with it?

What i did is, but i think is so long...:

```
if (this.object.name == '' || this.object.title == ''.......)
```

Thank you

Comment: No idea what you are trying to ask... but check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217419/how-to-determine-if-javascript-array-contains-an-object-with-an-attribute-that-e

Comment: Ok now i've updated it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my reputation is too low to ask this as a comment.

Where does the `object.property` gets its value from?
Are you using input fields on a form in your HTML?

If you are using a input fields on a form to capture `object.name` and `object.title` then it would be easier/best to use `form validators` with `formGroup` and `formBuilder`

`import{ Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl }from'@angular/forms';`

This will make sure that your object properties always have data in them or it will let you display to the end user that something is wrong with their information.

There is a lot of information out there on validators, but they are rather simple to implement, and it is mostly done on the `page.html`.

If you are getting your data from a service or just want to check the `object` 1 last time before you `doSomething()`  then you will need to loop through each of the properties in the object.

[Determining if all attributes on a javascript object are null or an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709636/determining-if-all-attributes-on-a-javascript-object-are-null-or-an-empty-string)

Comment: interesting, at the end I disabled a button till every field are with some info, thanks anyway :)